# How do I perform my "String.Format" call with correct localisation?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, internationalization

I am currently using this to create a string of a certain length from an integer variable. This is the only way I know of, at the moment; but Android Studio complains, saying it won't work work in all countries.

I will soon have some games that I might release on to the Play Store, and I wouldn't want there to be any unnecessary problems like this.

Is there a better way to achieve the same thing without reams of new code?

```
timeRemainingLabel = new Label(String.format("%03d", worldTimer), 
        new Label.LabelStyle(font, Color.WHITE));
```

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you mean by "a certain length String", but if you want to avoid using String.format, you could create a method that takes the integer as input and returns the string that you need.

Comment: ok thanks, what I mean by a certain length of string. Is the part above "%03d" tells the decoder to make it 3 digits long. so if the int is = 1 it will display "001"